# What is the best way to edit already-loaded HTML text using JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

The only way I know of to change the text on an HTML doc is to use javascript (jQuery).  Basically I'm trying to make a really simplified "cart" where I have a page with 5 links on it and whenever you click one of them it will add 1 to the "items in cart" counter on the page without having to reload the entire page.

I have a java class Cart that stores the current number of items in the cart and the names of the items in the cart.  I can easily make it so clicking a link/button on the page would add an item to this object, but what I can't figure out how to do is change the items number that is displayed on the page without reloading the entire page.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Using web-sockets is the right solution

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. This question is 'inherently opinion based' the way it is. It would be better to ask for some suggestions for alternative ways to update the content of the page.

Answer (score 0):

invoke a AJAX request (i.e. background javascript) from the web page to the server every 1 min, to get latest information. You can use Jquery to invoke AJAX request.

There should be Jquery sample code available via google to execute AJAX request to get new data, and also samples code to change HTML using the new data.

Comment: Almost every app that is not serving  thousands of users per second, will use this mechanism.